# JQuery - add/remove box on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a list that I've setup to have a "profile" box popout when you hover over a list item. I've accomplished the first step I want to achieve which is to pop the box out and then hide the box when hovering over another LI by using mouseenter and mouseleave. The next step is to keep the box shown because it has links and a vote button in this "profile" box. In short I want to hover over a list item show a box that remains shown until another LI is hovered over then hide previous box and show one being hovered.

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Maybe if you post your current code, someone might give you a hint on what to do next, using your variables, structure, etc. It increases your chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.hover()` (http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with both handlers, the first on hover and the second on leave.

For example something like this:

```
var popup = jQuery('#popup');

jQuery('li').hover(function(){
    popup.show();
}, function(){
    popup.hide();
});
```

Obviously you have to change `jQuery('#popup')` and `jQuery('li')` with the correct selector to catch the element of the popup that you want to show/hide, and the items in your list :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done a very barebones example.

In this example we utilize the hover event, the :visible selector, and the .hide() function.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Open This Box And Close Others<div>Hello</div></li>
    <li>No, Open This Box And Close Others<div>Goodbye</div></li>
    <li>How About Me<div>YOLO</div></li>
    <li>Hello...<div>WORLD!</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('li').on('hover', function(e) {
        $('div:visible').hide();
        $(this).find('div').show();
    });
});
```

Here is the example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybot1122/8eK8F/
Please keep in mind there will be many different ways to implement your behavior in JQuery. It is always worth searching and checking the JQuery API http://api.jquery.com/ for useful functions. Hope this was helpful!